# What does providing multiple interfaces in generic syntax while extending do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Following is the line in react that I don't understand. I know what partial does but its a little confusing. We could have extended them separately. Correct me if I am wrong. Following is the line of code:

```
export class SearchFilterPanelPositions extends Component<Partial<ISearchFilterPanelBasePropTypes & ISearchFilterPanelPropTypes>, ISearchTypesBaseState> { 

    ...
    ...
    }
```

What is the **SearchFilterPanelPositions** extending and how?

Comment: This is a logical `and` combining the bitmask to support both types at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) in TS make all properties of passed type argument optional. Sya we have

   ```
   interface ISearchFilterPanelBasePropTypes {
       prop1: string;
   }

   interface ISearchFilterPanelPropTypes {
       prop2: string;
   }
   ```

   After applying `Partial` to intersection of above interfaces we'll have type of shape:

   ```
   {
       prop1?: string;
   } & {
       prop2?: string;
   }
   ```

   So properties from both interfaces become optional (can be assigned `undefined`).
2. `Component` is React Component base type which has two type arguments, props and state. For props, above type is passed.

As a result, you'll have

```
export class SearchFilterPanelPositions extends Component<Partial<ISearchFilterPanelBasePropTypes & ISearchFilterPanelPropTypes>, ISearchTypesBaseState> { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        props.prop1 // can be string or undefined
        props.prop2 // can also be string or undefined
    }
    ...
    ...
    }
```

And above component can be used as

```
<SearchFilterPanelPositions /> // Without props
<SearchFilterPanelPositions prop1='prop1' /> // With only prop1 provided
<SearchFilterPanelPositions prop1='prop1' prop2='prop2' /> // Both prop1 and prop2 provided
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.